# Having a hard time with cases (c#/XNA)

Tags: c#, xna

I'm attempting to program Pong for an assignment in a programming course, but errors popped up when I attempted to make a main menu using cases. Code is in the update area of an XNA Window's Game. The code in the playing case ran fine on its own. The issues arise when I attempted to make a main menu and moved my pong code to the playing case

```
switch (CurrentGameState)
{
    case GameState.MainMenu:
        if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
        btnPlay.Update(mouse);
        break;

    case GameState.Playing:
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            if (POPBox.Y >= 373)
            {
                POPBox.Y += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                POPBox.Y += PlayersSpeed;
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                if (POPBox.Y <= 0)
                {
                    POPBox.Y += 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    POPBox.Y += -PlayersSpeed;
                }
            }

            // Ball Limets
            if (BallBox.Y <= 0)
                VelocityY *= -1;
            if (BallBox.Y >= 463)
                VelocityY *= -1;
            if (BallBox.X <= 0)
                VelocityX *= -1;

            //Collision Detection (Runs this code if it hits the player one's paddle)
            if (BallBox.Intersects(POPBox))
            {
                //Used to deflect in different directions for some veriety
                if (PlayersSpeed > 0)
                    VelocityY += 3;
                if (PlayersSpeed < 0)
                    VelocityY -= 3;

                VelocityX *= -1;
                HitCount++;
                ShockerGeneratorPlayerOne();

                //Stopping the no slope bug. If it wants to bounce perfectly straight, it is slightly shifty to fix that error.
                if (VelocityY == 0)
                    VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                if (VelocityX == 0)
                    VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;

                //speed control
                if (VelocityX > 10)
                    VelocityX = 10;
                if (VelocityY > 10)
                    VelocityY = 10;
            }

            // Runs this code if the ball hits player two's paddle
            if (BallBox.Intersects(PTPBox))
            {
                VelocityX *= -1;
                ShockerGeneratorPlayerTwo();

                if (VelocityY == 0)
                     VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                if (VelocityX == 0)
                    VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;
            }

            //Object a collision
            if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectARectangle))
            {
                VelocityY *= -1;
            }

            if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectBRectangle))
            {
                VelocityX *= -1;
            }

            // If Player One Loses
            if (BallBox.X >= 790)
            {
                PlayerOneLoses();
            }

            //Player Two's "AI" and limets
            if (PTPBox.Y >= 173)
                PTPBox.Y += 0;
            else
                PTPBox.Y = BallBox.Y;

            if (PTPBox.Y <= 0)
                PTPBox.Y += 0;
            else
                PTPBox.Y = (BallBox.Y -30);

            //Object A movement code
            ShocObjectARectangle.X += ObjectASpeed;
            if (ShocObjectARectangle.X <= 80)
                ObjectASpeed *= -1;
            else if (ShocObjectARectangle.X >= 600)
                ObjectASpeed *= -1;

            //Object B movement code
            ShocObjectBRectangle.Y += ObjectBSpeed;

            if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y <= 0)
                ObjectBSpeed *= -1;
            else if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y >= 415)
                ObjectBSpeed *= -1;

            // Ball Velocity
            BallBox.Y += -VelocityY;
            BallBox.X += VelocityX;
            PlayersSpeed = 10;
        }
    }
}


//Called Every Hit
public void ShockerGeneratorPlayerOne()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    RanShocMatch = rnd.Next(10);
    if (RanShocMatch == 1)
    {
    //Speed Boost!
        VelocityX = (VelocityX - 1);
        VelocityY = (VelocityY - 1);
    }
    else if (RanShocMatch == 2)
        {
            if (ObjectBCalled == false)
            {
                ShocObjectBRectangle = new Rectangle(362, 200, 10, 100);
                ObjectBCalled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (RanShocMatch == 3)
            {
                if (ObjectACalled == false)
                {
                    ShocObjectARectangle = new Rectangle(80, 200, 100, 10);
                    ObjectACalled = true;
                }
            }
}

//Called Every Hit
public void ShockerGeneratorPlayerTwo()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    RanShocMatch = rnd.Next(5);

    if (RanShocMatch == 1)
    {
        //Speed Boost!
        VelocityX = (VelocityX + 3);
        VelocityY = (VelocityY + 3);
    }
}

//Called When Player One Loses
public void PlayerOneLoses()
{
    // MediaPlayer.Play(LosingBeep);
    VelocityX = -BasicVelocity;
    VelocityY = BasicVelocity;
    BallBox.X += -360;

    if (HitCount > highScore)
        highScore = HitCount;
        HitCount = 0;
        break;  
}

}                
}                     

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Errors:

1. A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
2. Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
3. Control cannot fall through from one case label
4. No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue

I'm new to these forums and my formatting is abysmal, if you have any tips to improve it I'll make an edit.

Comment: You're most likely missing a bracket somewhere and it's having a butterfly-error-effect on the rest of your code.  Press Ctrl `K D` -- which should auto format your code, and I bet it vomits.

Comment: Definitely looks like a missing bracket somewhere

Comment: You should also consider to reduce the amount of else-if else-if by analysing your code !

Comment: I pasted the whole thing into a code page and intellisense went berserk.  Definitely a missing bracket.

Comment: I think gamestate.playing is missing the bracket, just double checking..

Comment: Yep, for the (if keys.down)

Comment: If you have a good style of formatting code during development, you will immediately see the problems in the logic of the code. This allows you to avoid many errors. P.S. Also missed "break" for second case.

Answer (score 1):

It looked like you highlighted code and moved it downwards, try this

Update method

```
 switch (CurrentGameState)
            {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
                btnPlay.Update(mouse);
                break;
            case GameState.Playing:
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                {
                    if (POPBox.Y >= 373)
                    {
                        POPBox.Y += 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        POPBox.Y += PlayersSpeed;
                    }
                }

                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                {
                    if (POPBox.Y <= 0)
                    {
                        POPBox.Y += 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        POPBox.Y += -PlayersSpeed;
                    }
                }
                // Ball Limets
                if (BallBox.Y <= 0)
                    VelocityY *= -1;
                if (BallBox.Y >= 463)
                    VelocityY *= -1;
                if (BallBox.X <= 0)
                    VelocityX *= -1;
                //Collision Detection (Runs this code if it hits the player one's paddle)
                if (BallBox.Intersects(POPBox))
                {
                    //Used to deflect in different directions for some veriety
                    if (PlayersSpeed > 0)
                        VelocityY += 3;
                    if (PlayersSpeed < 0)
                        VelocityY -= 3;
                    VelocityX *= -1;
                    HitCount++;
                    ShockerGeneratorPlayerOne();
                    //Stopping the no slope bug. If it wants to bounce perfectly straight,                it is slightly shifty to fix that error.
                    if (VelocityY == 0)
                        VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                    if (VelocityX == 0)
                        VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;
                    //speed control
                    if (VelocityX > 10)
                        VelocityX = 10;
                    if (VelocityY > 10)
                        VelocityY = 10;
                 }
                // Runs this code if the ball hits player two's paddle
                if (BallBox.Intersects(PTPBox))
                {
                    VelocityX *= -1;
                    ShockerGeneratorPlayerTwo();
                    if (VelocityY == 0)
                        VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                    if (VelocityX == 0)
                        VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;
                }

                //Object a collision
                if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectARectangle))
                {
                    VelocityY *= -1;
                }
                if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectBRectangle))
                {
                    VelocityX *= -1;
                }
                // If Player One Loses
                if (BallBox.X >= 790)
                {
                    PlayerOneLoses();
                }
                //Player Two's "AI" and limets
                if (PTPBox.Y >= 173)
                    PTPBox.Y += 0;
                else
                    PTPBox.Y = BallBox.Y;

                if (PTPBox.Y <= 0)
                    PTPBox.Y += 0;
                else
                    PTPBox.Y = (BallBox.Y -30);
                //Object A movement code
                ShocObjectARectangle.X += ObjectASpeed;
                if (ShocObjectARectangle.X <= 80)
                    ObjectASpeed *= -1;
                else if (ShocObjectARectangle.X >= 600)
                    ObjectASpeed *= -1;
                //Object B movement code
                ShocObjectBRectangle.Y += ObjectBSpeed;
                if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y <= 0)
                    ObjectBSpeed *= -1;
                else if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y >= 415)
                    ObjectBSpeed *= -1;
                // Ball Velocity
                BallBox.Y += -VelocityY;
                BallBox.X += VelocityX;
                PlayersSpeed = 10;
                break;
            }
        base.Update(gameTime);
```

And your other 3 methods

```
                //Called Every Hit
                public void ShockerGeneratorPlayerOne()
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    RanShocMatch = rnd.Next(10);
                    if (RanShocMatch == 1)
                    {
                    //Speed Boost!
                        VelocityX = (VelocityX - 1);
                        VelocityY = (VelocityY - 1);
                    }
                    else if (RanShocMatch == 2)
                    {
                        if (ObjectBCalled == false)
                        {
                            ShocObjectBRectangle = new Rectangle(362, 200, 10, 100);
                            ObjectBCalled = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (RanShocMatch == 3)
                    {
                        if (ObjectACalled == false)
                        {
                            ShocObjectARectangle = new Rectangle(80, 200, 100, 10);
                            ObjectACalled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Called Every Hit
                public void ShockerGeneratorPlayerTwo()
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    RanShocMatch = rnd.Next(5);
                    if (RanShocMatch == 1)
                    {
                    //Speed Boost!
                        VelocityX = (VelocityX + 3);
                        VelocityY = (VelocityY + 3);
                    }
                }

                //Called When Player One Loses
                public void PlayerOneLoses()
                {
                // MediaPlayer.Play(LosingBeep);
                    VelocityX = -BasicVelocity;
                    VelocityY = BasicVelocity;
                    BallBox.X += -360;
                    if (HitCount > highScore)
                        highScore = HitCount;
                    HitCount = 0;
                }
```

Comment: Note: best way to try this is to delete your inner code for `Update`, (and 3 methods if you wish) make sure your code compiles and then enter these 3 methods, cause i believe you had too many closing brackets at the end too